# Non-Renewal subscription in-app purchase clarification needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a requirement to implement monthly subscription plans to radio channels in the iPhone app. These radio channels are creating by the admin through web backend. **Channels have its own unlock price**. And also, the **admin can add channels dynamically**.
So, my first question is

1. How do I implement Non-Renewal subscription in-app purchase for this kind of products set?
   Do I need to manually add a product in iTunesConnect, each time the system admin add a new channel? If I do like that, I have to submit an app update also with the new in-app products?

My second question is,

2. Can I implement this subscription plans without using iTunesConnect in-app purchases? Will Apple reject the app if I use a third party mechanism to implement subscriptions?

Other issue, I am facing is this app going to be a on Android platform also, In that case, if the user subscribe to a channel, he/she should able to use that subscription on any platform he/she uses.

Your thoughts and suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to upload a new application on Apple Store every time. You can fetch the product dynamically using store kit api. Then you can manage your view accordingly.
2. Yes, Apple will reject your application. For more info refer [In App Purchase Policy Section](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies)
3. For the Android, You can store the expiration date in the backend database, which you can use to check on other platform. Android do have alternative to In App purchase called [In App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html), You can use that in Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance, I decide to give it a shot without using apple inn-app purchases since this product supports three platforms web, iOS and Android. Also, the client needs to use a third party payment system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Products need to be added to iTunes Connect. You don't need to submit an app update when you add new products - you are able to download the products using StoreKit from within your app. You'd then display them and allow the user to choose which product they would like to purchase and go from there.
2. Yes. Apple only allow in-app purchases using their in-app purchase API.

You're going to have to work around this and come up with a solution for Android that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your best option is to sell token packages (50 tokens, 100 tokens, etc) in-app purchase as non-renewal items. Then your users can use these tokens to add radio channels or whatever product you have. This way you can add new products easily and switching between android and ios is not a problem. We submitted an app using this in-app purchase model and it is approved.